Number of 5-digit positive integers consisting of exactly 3 distinct digits, e.g. 70220.
The main motivation for posting this is not being certain about the second part using the proposed strategy. My answer deviates from the answer given on an educational website, but I can't see my error. I'm aware of similar questions questions having been posted, but not exactly the same. Moreover, I'm interested not so much in the correct answer (that too of course) but ensuring (potentially fixing) that my strategy is fine.
My strategy is to divide the problem into counting numbers without zero and those containing zero.
Those without zero are easy. We count all the strings of length 5 over an alphabet containing 3 symbols, and then subtract all the strings that contain at most 2 symbols over that alphabet, and account for the number of over-subtracted strings using inclusion-exclusion. Then, we multiply the whole lot by all possible choices of 3 symbols from a 9 symbol alphabet:
$$\binom{9}{3} \cdot \left[ 3^5 - \binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^5 +3 \right]$$
The idea to count all the numbers with zero that satisfy the condition is to count all the strings of length 4 consisting of only zero and exactly two other digits using a similar (inclusion-exclusion) approach and extending them to 5 digit numbers multiplying the result by 2 - extending by one digit or the other. Also the result is to be multiplied by all the ways we can choose two digits from nine (since zero is assumed to be already present). This gives:
$$\binom{9}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot \left[ 3^4 - \binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^4 +3 \right]$$
So the final result is:
$$\binom{9}{3} \cdot \left[ 3^5 - \binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^5 +3 \right] + 2 \cdot \binom{9}{2} \cdot \left[ 3^4 - \binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^4 +3 \right] = 15192$$
I'm quite confident about the correctness of the first part, but perhaps the discrepency between my answer and the one given on the educational website could be due to an error in the second part? I may have done some obvious, stupid error that I can't see or they have the wrong answer, and I'll be happy to correct them. The final answer they give is $16200$.

How does multiplying by 2 give you the 5 digit numbers?

Each string of length 4, eg. 0203 is extended by either of the non-zero digits, ie. 20203 and 30203. That’s two extensions for every string of length 4 that consists of zero and two other digits.

Indeed your method for counting the five digit numbers with no zeros is correct. However, you are undercounting the numbers including zero. Specifically, your method does not account for numbers like $10022$, where the only place one of the digits appears is in the beginning. We can count those by choosing a pair of non-zero digits, and counting the number of four digit numbers using only zero and one of those two digits, and then multiplying the whole by two. In other words
$$
2\binom{9}{2}\left(2^4-2\right) = 1008. 
$$
Adding this to what you already computed yields $16200$, as expected.

Ah, great, thank you!

@MariuszPopieluch no problem.

While your strategy is ok, there is a simpler way avoiding cases.
Left to myself, I'd just solve it in one step as
$$\binom{10}{3} \cdot \left[ 3^5 - \binom{3}{2}\cdot 2^5 +3 \right]\times 0.9 = 16200$$
using the fact that the probability the $1st$ digit was zero would be $0.1$

Indeed! Very nice. As a matter of fact I also thought of this solution last night, and was going to add it in an edit this morning. You bet me to it! :) I gave an answer to a similar question, for counting all strings of length 5 with the same constraint. Last night I also realised that a simple symmetry argument could transform that answer to the question above!

Glad you like it ! I got engrossed in trying to find the loopholes in the second case  before looking at the question with a fresh eye, else it would have been the first answer ! $;;$
